# Jquery cannot select combobox on the first page's load

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have page with 3 subpage.
when i first accessed the page it means i open the first subpage. "Jenis Kartu Identitas" (combobox) column in first subpage selecting the first value while it has own value. but, when i move to the second subpage and go back to fisrt subpage, it works normally.
thanks in advance.

first condition

[image]

second condition (what i want)

[image]

heres my source:

```js
$('#idCardType').val("KTP03").trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select name="idCardType" id="idCardType" class="form-control input-sm select2">
<option value="KTP01">KTP</option>
<option value="KTP02">KTP Seumur Hidup</option>
<option value="KTP03">Resi/Surat Domisili</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where/when do you run your script?  Is it in the `<head>` ? end of `<body>`? Is it inside doc.ready?   Your snippet implies you're using `select2` - does your script run before/after select2 is initialised?  Can you updated your snippet to *demonstrate* the behaviour?  (the current snippet shows it working, so it's *obviously* not just a case of .val().trigger() not working and will be due to when you call it, which you've **not included the relevant information**.

Comment: thanks for the help. but it's already works. i delaying the trigger function and my code looks like this :
`setTimeout(function () {
 $('#idCardType').val(obj.idTypeCode).trigger('change');
 }, 100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should set selected="selected" for the option, for example KTP01.
Second way i think, delaying the trigger function might works.

something like that:

> setTimeout(() => { $('#idCardType').val("KTP03").trigger('change'); }, 500);

Comment: ahh you save my day. i just tried to delaying the trigger function and it works. thank you mate.

Comment: then its about your init call function executes 'before' it rendering objects. so cannot set the selected item onLoad and this is because when you move to the second subpage and go back to fisrt subpage, it works normally i think =) you're welcome